# LWJGL not showing textures

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, slick2d

Having problems showing the textures on my 3D box in LWJGL using slick. 
Earlier I had the error:

```
WARN:class org.newdawn.slick.opengl.PNGImageData failed to read the data
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported format for this image
```

Saying it couldnt read the image. So I converted the image to 24bit (also tried 8bit) and now i only get:

```
INFO:Use Java PNG Loader = true
```

My 3D cube is shown but no textures on it. Dont know what to do to make it show my textures.

Textures class:

```
    package com.base.engine;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

public class Texture {
    private int id;

    public Texture(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void bind() {
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);

    }

    public int getID() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Material class

```
package com.base.engine;

public class Material
{
    private Texture texture;
    private Vector3f color;

    public Material(Texture texture)
    {
        this(texture, new Vector3f(1,1,1));
    }

    public Material(Texture texture, Vector3f color)
    {
        this.texture = texture;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Texture getTexture()
    {
        return texture;
    }

    public void setTexture(Texture texture)
    {
        this.texture = texture;
    }

    public Vector3f getColor()
    {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Vector3f color)
    {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

Game class:

```
package com.base.engine;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;



public class Game 
{
    private Mesh mesh;
    private Shader shader;
    private Material material;
    private Transform transform;
    private Camera camera;



    public Game()
    {

        mesh = ResourceLoader.loadMesh("box.obj");
        material = new Material(ResourceLoader.loadTexture("test.png"), new Vector3f(0,1,1));


        shader = BasicShader.getInstance();
        camera = new Camera();

//      Vertex[] vertices = new Vertex[] {new Vertex(new Vector3f(-1,-1,0), new Vector2f(0,0)),
//                                    new Vertex(new Vector3f(0,1,0), new Vector2f(0.5f,0)),
//                                    new Vertex(new Vector3f(1,-1,0), new Vector2f(1.0f,0)),
//                                    new Vertex(new Vector3f(0,-1,1), new Vector2f(0.5f,1.0f))};
//      
//      int[] indices = new int[] {3,1,0,
//                                 2,1,3,
//                                 0,1,2,
//                                 0,2,3};
//      
//      mesh.addVertices(vertices, indices);

        Transform.setProjection(70f, Window.getWidth(), Window.getHeight(), 0.1f, 1000);
        Transform.setCamera(camera);
        transform = new Transform();
    }

    public void input()
    {
        camera.input();

//      if(Input.getKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP))
//          System.out.println("We've just pressed up!");
//      if(Input.getKeyUp(Input.KEY_UP))
//          System.out.println("We've just released up!");
//      
//      if(Input.getMouseDown(1))
//          System.out.println("We've just right clicked at " + Input.getMousePosition().toString());
//      if(Input.getMouseUp(1))
//          System.out.println("We've just released right mouse button!");
    }

    float temp = 0.0f;

    public void update()
    {
        temp += Time.getDelta();

        float sinTemp = (float)Math.sin(temp);

        transform.setTranslation(sinTemp, 0, 5);
        transform.setRotation(0, sinTemp * 180, 0);
        //transform.setScale(0.7f * sinTemp, 0.7f * sinTemp, 0.7f * sinTemp);
    }

    public void render()
    {
        RenderUtil.setClearColor(Transform.getCamera().getPos().div(2048f).abs());

        shader.bind();
        shader.updateUniforms(transform.getTransformation(), transform.getProjectedTransformation(), material);
        mesh.draw();
    }
}
```

RenderUtil class:

```
package com.base.engine;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

public class RenderUtil
{
    public static void clearScreen()
    {
        //TODO: Stencil Buffer
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    public static void setTextures(boolean enabled)
    {
        if(enabled)
            glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        else
            glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }

    public static void unbindTextures()
    {
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    }

    public static void setClearColor(Vector3f color)
    {
        glClearColor(color.getX(), color.getY(), color.getZ(), 1.0f);
    }

    public static void initGraphics()
    {
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        glFrontFace(GL_CW);
        glCullFace(GL_BACK);
        glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        //TODO: Depth clamp for later

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glEnable(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB);
    }

    public static String getOpenGLVersion()
    {
        return glGetString(GL_VERSION);
    }
}
```

Shader class:

```
package com.base.engine;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL32.*;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class Shader
{
    private int program;
    private HashMap<String, Integer> uniforms;

    public Shader()
    {
        program = glCreateProgram();
        uniforms = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        if(program == 0)
        {
            System.err.println("Shader creation failed: Could not find valid memory location in constructor");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public void bind()
    {
        glUseProgram(program);
    }

    public void updateUniforms(Matrix4f worldMatrix, Matrix4f projectedMatrix, Material material)
    {

    }

    public void addUniform(String uniform)
    {
        int uniformLocation = glGetUniformLocation(program, uniform);

        if(uniformLocation == 0xFFFFFFFF)
        {
            System.err.println("Error: Could not find uniform: " + uniform);
            new Exception().printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        uniforms.put(uniform, uniformLocation);
    }

    public void addVertexShader(String text)
    {
        addProgram(text, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    }

    public void addGeometryShader(String text)
    {
        addProgram(text, GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER);
    }

    public void addFragmentShader(String text)
    {
        addProgram(text, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    }

    public void compileShader()
    {
        glLinkProgram(program);

        if(glGetProgram(program, GL_LINK_STATUS) == 0)
        {
            System.err.println(glGetProgramInfoLog(program, 1024));
            System.exit(1);
        }

        glValidateProgram(program);

        if(glGetProgram(program, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS) == 0)
        {
            System.err.println(glGetProgramInfoLog(program, 1024));
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    private void addProgram(String text, int type)
    {
        int shader = glCreateShader(type);

        if(shader == 0)
        {
            System.err.println("Shader creation failed: Could not find valid memory location when adding shader");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        glShaderSource(shader, text);
        glCompileShader(shader);

        if(glGetShader(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == 0)
        {
            System.err.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, 1024));
            System.exit(1);
        }

        glAttachShader(program, shader);
    }

    public void setUniformi(String uniformName, int value)
    {
        glUniform1i(uniforms.get(uniformName), value);
    }

    public void setUniformf(String uniformName, float value)
    {
        glUniform1f(uniforms.get(uniformName), value);
    }

    public void setUniform(String uniformName, Vector3f value)
    {
        glUniform3f(uniforms.get(uniformName), value.getX(), value.getY(), value.getZ());
    }

    public void setUniform(String uniformName, Matrix4f value)
    {
        glUniformMatrix4(uniforms.get(uniformName), true, Util.createFlippedBuffer(value));
    }
}
```

BasicShader class:

```
package com.base.engine;

public class BasicShader extends Shader
{
    private static final BasicShader instance = new BasicShader();

    public static BasicShader getInstance()
    {
        return instance;
    }

    private BasicShader()
    {
        super();

        addVertexShader(ResourceLoader.loadShader("basicVertex.vs"));
        addFragmentShader(ResourceLoader.loadShader("basicFragment.fs"));
        compileShader();

        addUniform("transform");
        addUniform("color");
    }

    public void updateUniforms(Matrix4f worldMatrix, Matrix4f projectedMatrix, Material material)
    {
        if(material.getTexture() != null)
            material.getTexture().bind();
        else
            RenderUtil.unbindTextures();

        setUniform("transform", projectedMatrix);
        setUniform("color", material.getColor());
    }
}
```

basicVertex.vs

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 texCoord;

out vec2 texCoord0;

uniform mat4 transform;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = transform * vec4(position, 1.0);
    texCoord0 = texCoord;
}
```

basicFragment.fs

```
#version 330

in vec2 texCoord0;

out vec4 fragColor;

uniform vec3 color;
uniform sampler2D sampler;

void main()
{
    vec4 textureColor = texture(sampler, texCoord0.xy);

    if(textureColor == vec4(0,0,0,0))
        fragColor = vec4(color, 1);
    else
        fragColor = textureColor * vec4(color, 1);
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Next time, please limit the amount of code, down to where the problem actually exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the code you have provided, you have never actually bound a texture.

I see you have imported `org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*` but have something called a "shader" that you bind in your code. Are you using the fixed-function pipeline or shaders? I ask because if you really are using only OpenGL 1.1 in your software, you will also need to enable `GL_TEXTURE_2D`.

Comment: I am enabling it in the Render Util class. I have added that class and the Shader class above now.

Comment: My point still stand - you never actually call `Texture.bind (...)` anywhere. The closest you come is binding a shader. You need to bind your texture, not just enable it. Likewise, you never set the value of your sampler2D uniform in your shader anywhere. Could you include your shader as well?

Comment: I have included them now. 
Om actually following a tutorial on youtube by thebennybox: 

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_54jIrhyQM&list=PLEETnX-uPtBXP_B2yupUKlflXBznWIlL5&index=22

Noticed now that the cube color changes when I change the texture image. Does that mean anything to you?

Comment: It tells me you didn't setup your texture coordinates. And that is also what I can see just by looking at your code.

Comment: Thank you! 
Got it working by redoing the code acording to this: https://github.com/BennyQBD/3DGameEngine/tree/eee77c9b456265019c6faf52af5a72c1cd7b9b6f/src/com/base/engine

I dont really get why it works now but didnt before, but I get that i never set the coordinates of the texture and thats what made it not to show up. I just dont know where this should be done.